# Как реализовать отправку сгенерированных данных постоянно работающим процессом?

Tags: c++, веб-сервер, unix, raspberry-pi, http-server

Реализую http-сервер, для управления роботом на основе малины. Идея такая - сервер стоящий на малине в начале своей работы создает процессы, который будут работать постоянно и выполнять основные функции робота(взять видеопоток с вебкамеры, управление элементами робота через ком порты и тд). Смысл в том, что такой способ, по идее, должен давать повышенную производительность, т.к не нужно тратить время на создание процесса, запуск интерпретаторов и тд. Проблема в том, что я не могу придумать решение, как обращаться к сгенерированным этими процессами данным. В обычном простеньком сервере, на каждый запрос создается новый процесс, который генерирует данные, тут же процессы уже созданы. В с++, насколько я знаю, нет возможности создать буфер с именем в ходе работы программы. Следовательно мы не можем обратиться к буферу, в которым хранятся данные, сгенерированные этим процессом.

Иными словами.Процессы должны работать всегда, не зависимо от того, есть запросы на генерируемые ими данные или нет. Данные генерируемые процессами должны складываться в какой то буфер, из которого уже будут браться ответы на запросы от пользователей. Эти процессы не должны быть статическими, я хочу добавлять их в зависимости от конфигурации, по этому я не могу сделать статический буфер с именем.

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтоб когда нам приходит запрос на данные, сгенерированные процессом, мы могли бы обратиться к ним и вернуть клиенту?

Comment: *"обычном простеньком сервере, на каждый запрос создается новый процесс"* - обычно процесс либо один, либо пул переиспользуемых процессов. *"нет возможности создать буфер с именем в ходе работы программы"* - почему нет?

Comment: @user7860670, если есть, подскажите пожалуйста. Я знаю только переменные окружения, но, на мой взгляд, они не очень подходят для данной задачи.

Comment: @user7860670, насколько я знаю, существует много видов архитектуры серверов, и самая первая и простая из них это - один запрос , один процесс.

Comment: вы не путаете процесс и поток? межпроцессное и межпотоковое взаимодействие, это два разных понятия

Comment: @DenverToha При чем тут переменные окружения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы же сами уже расписали всю архитектуру

> Данные генерируемые процессами должны складываться в какой то буффер, из которого уже будут браться ответы на запросы от пользователей.

> Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтоб когда нам приходит запрос, на данные сгенерированные пермонентным процессом, мы могли бы обратиться к ним и вернуть клиенту?

Вам нужен еще один элемент под названием "менеджер буферов". Его функционал простой

1. Каждый процесс по старту создает буфер под свои данные и регистрирует его в менеджере. Скажем передает некий собственный идентификатор (имя этого буфера), указатель на буфер и длину.
2. Клиент, подключаясь к системе обращается к этому менеджеру и просит вернуть ему буфер для указанного идентификатора
3. В зависимости от того был ли зарегистрирован буфер с этим идентификатором клиент получает указатель на него или null
4. Далее клиент напрямую работает с буфером процесса
5. При окончании процесса буфер разрегистрируется в менеджере

Добавить синхронизацию менеджера и буферов для многопоточной работы и все готово